# PHP : Can retrieve data from db but can not insert

Tags: php, mysql

What am I trying to do is :

insert data into a table having two columns and showing the updated value in the same php page. I am able to fetch data and show it but not able to insert any. Please guide me.

file is named as mypage.php

My code so far :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to mysqli: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {

    if(isset($_POST['url']) && isset($_POST['desc'])) 
    {
        $url=$_POST['url'];
        $desc=$_POST['desc'];
        $sql=   "INSERT INTO urldesc ".
                "(url,desc) ".
                "VALUES ('".$url."', '".$desc."')";
        echo $sql;
        echo $url;
        echo $desc;
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        //mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO urldesc (url, desc) VALUES ('". $_POST['url'] ."', '". $_POST['desc'] ."')");
    }
  }

?>

<html>
    <body>
    <form action="mypage.php" method='post'>
        <input type="text" name='url' />
        <input type="text" name='desc' />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
        <table border=1>
            <th>URL</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <?php
            $values=mysqli_query($con,"select * from urldesc");
            if(! $values )
            {
              die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($values))
            {
                echo "<tr><td width='200px'><center>".$row['url']."</center></td><td width='600px'><center>".$row['desc']."</center></td></tr>";
            } 
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>  
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried running the query in phpmyadmin whatever gets echoed by "echo $sql"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following statement

```
 $sql=   "INSERT INTO urldesc ".
            "(url,desc) ".
            "VALUES ('".$url."', '".$desc."')";
```

To

```
 $sql=   "INSERT INTO urldesc ".
            "(`url`,`desc`) ".
            "VALUES ('".$url."', '".$desc."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your given parameter to `mysqli_qurey` is wrong format. you use `mysqli_query($con, $sql)` but it should be `mysqli_query($sql, $con)`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to mysqli: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {

    if(isset($_POST['url']) && isset($_POST['desc'])) 
    {
        $url=$_POST['url'];
        $desc=$_POST['desc'];
        $sql=   "INSERT INTO `urldesc` ".
                "(`url`,`desc`) ".
                "VALUES ('".$url."', '".$desc."')";
        echo $sql;
        echo $url;
        echo $desc;
        mysqli_query($sql, $con);
        //mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO urldesc (url, desc) VALUES ('". $_POST['url'] ."', '". $_POST['desc'] ."')");
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: i get this : Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\test\mypage.php on line 22

Comment: check your mysqli connection. is you connect to mysql successfully?. check your `$con`